# Signal Generator & Accessory

Tags: signal, frequency, generator

Are these 2 products compatible with each other?

https://www.spooky2-mall.com/product/spooky2-cold-laser-twin-free-shipping-via-china-post/

[https://www.amazon.com/Koolertron-Generator-Precision-Dual-channel-Arbitrary/dp/B07211YWMK/ref=pd_ybh_a_9?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5M0CDG6CBTGCX3HP6C73](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07211YWMK)

Comment: compatible in what way? ... which specs are you referring to? ... you posted links to online stores, not to data sheets

Comment: Don't just copy and paste stuff into the comments section, edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the sense that the magic therapy thing is BNC and specifies a frequency range that the synthesizer is capable of producing.